# INNER JOIN em 4 tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Tenho 4 tabelas:

**TB_OS_MANUTENCAO:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TB_OS_ELETRONICA:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TB_OS_MECANICA:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E TB_OS_INFORMATICA:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como mostrado nas imagens, todas as tabelas tem um campo em comum, o id_chamado, e também com um valor em comum, o 8. Esse campo não esta marcado como UNIQUE e nem outro tipo, é um campo tinyint normal. O problema é que não estou conseguindo bolar nenhum comando SQL com INNER JOINS que capture TODOS (*) os dados das 4 tabelas aonde esse id_chamado (8) seja igual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM TB_OS_MANUTENCAO ma
INNER JOIN TB_OS_ELETRONICA el ON el.id_chamado = ma.id_chamado
INNER JOIN TB_OS_MECANICA me ON me.id_chamado = el.id_chamado
INNER JOIN TB_OS_INFORMATICA if ON if.id_chamado = me.id_chamado
WHERE me.id_chamado = 8
```

Ou

```sql
SELECT * FROM TB_OS_MANUTENCAO ma,TB_OS_ELETRONICA el,TB_OS_MECANICA me,TB_OS_INFORMATICA if
WHERE el.id_chamado = ma.id_chamado
  AND me.id_chamado = el.id_chamado
  AND if.id_chamado = me.id_chamado
  AND me.id_chamado = 8
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Amigo.. mais uma rápida ajuda.. sua consulta deu certo, mas quando faço a query ele retorna essa mensagem: " Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available" e os dados retornam tudo junto, uma do lado da outra, sem pular linha. Na solução é só eu marcar o campo id_chamado como unique ?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá,

Caso o seu banco de dados seja o MySQL, segue essas dicas.

Se você estiver usando "phpMyAdmin" versão anterior a 4.6.0, atualizar para a mais recente, mas se fosse você eu instalaria a Ide "MySql WorkBench CE"

Comment: Você pode editar a sua resposta, não precisa criar outro para complementar ;)